# Unable to start nextcloud docker container on a raspberry pi 4

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, nextcloud

I try to start a docker nextcloud server on a Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB) with this command:

```
> docker run -p 8083:80 nextcloud
```

The container does not start and I get this error:

```
touch: setting times of '/var/www/html/nextcloud-init-sync.lock': Operation not permitted
```

In the morning I sucessfully started docker nextcloud server with the same command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should not happen because you start a completely new container. I don't see any mounted volumes in your command which could cause this issue. Maybe you have made a `docker commit` to this image?
Anyway I could not reproduce it on my rpi4.